# Azure AD Role Based Authorization : Allow specific roles for all GET methods and another set of roles for POSTS

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-authentication

There is a need to authorize the Users based on their Roles, particularly a set of roles that should allow all GET operations and a second set that should allow all POST operations.

**Eg:**

- All Get methods should be accessible to the reader
- Post method access is granted to contributors

I don't want to mark the individual methods with the [Authorize()] as I have ~20 controllers with each supporting all 4 Http Verbs.

I have implemented something like this

```
[RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute(new string[2] { "CJE.Reader", "CJE.Contributor" }, new string[1] { "CJE.Contributor" }, new string[1] { "CJE.Contributor" }, new string[1] { "CJE.Contributor" })]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
```

and

```
public sealed class RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute(string[] getRoleMap, string[] postRoleMap, string[] putRoleMap, string[] deleteRoleMap)
    {
        this.GetRoleMap = getRoleMap;
        this.PostRoleMap = postRoleMap;
        this.PutRoleMap = putRoleMap;
        this.DeleteRoleMap = deleteRoleMap;
    }

    public string[] GetRoleMap { get; }

    public string[] PostRoleMap { get; }

    public string[] PutRoleMap { get; }

    public string[] DeleteRoleMap { get; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!this.IsUserAllowed(context))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    private bool IsUserAllowed(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value);

        switch (context.HttpContext.Request.Method)
        {
            case "GET":
                return this.GetRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            case "POST":
                return this.PostRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            case "PUT":
                return this.PutRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            case "DELETE":
                return this.DeleteRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine. However, I feel that this needs to be optimized. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good approach and while you could also consider [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you would eventually end up with code/logic similar to what you have tried already.